# "Guesswork", "guesstimation" synonyms

Tags: synonyms, idiom-requests

I'm looking for idioms and synonyms for "guesswork". Especially i'm looking for idioms and synonyms for given word connected to unscientific ways of predicting future. Both - pejorative and positive - idioms and synonyms are welcome.

Comment: A good dictionary and thesaurus will give you all the synonyms you need.  As regards idioms *the finger in the air method*, is the first one that comes to my mind.

Comment: My previous team used SWAG (*Scientific Wild Ass Guess*) a lot.

Comment: pinning the tail to the donkey, lets play blindfold darts, thats what I had to put up with. 'read the tea leaves' was my personal fave rave.

Comment: Nice one @DanBron

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I was wondering if "read..." has an English counterpart! Thanks for that!

Comment: @data - there are scientific ways of predicting the future?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Probably Cross Validated is better place to discuss this - you touch pretty deep problem here. For instance - as far as I know the question to tell scientific method from the rest is still a valid question - e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrology_and_science#.22No_puzzles_to_solve.22 . And my more down to earth motivation was following - I used work "unscientific" because I wanted to provide extra indication for people willing to contribute.

Comment: *Educated guess* and its contraction, *[guesstimate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guesstimate)* are both valid here.  I know "guesstimation" was used in the question's title, but at least that form isn't in my browser's dictionary while "guesstimate" actually is (Google Ngrams [suggests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=guesstimate%2Cguestimate&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900) that the double-s spelling is preferred by over 5x).

Comment: @AdamKatz Thanks for that comment - I didn't know that Google is offering such a handy tool!

Comment: @data, I have converted that comment to an answer.  Also, yes: Google Ngrams is awesome and a half.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with ***[guesstimate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guesstimate)***, which is often used as a term for an *educated guess* (which is also a valid answer), though I don't see that in any definitions.

> **guesstimate** (n) (informal). An estimate that is hardly any better than a guess, often because it is based on insufficient or unreliable data.

I know "guesstimation" was used in the question's title, but at least that form isn't in my browser's dictionary while "guesstimate" actually is (both are present in Wiktionary).

(Google Ngrams [suggests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=guesstimate%2Cguestimate&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900) that the double-s spelling is preferred by over 5x, and the single-s spelling isn't in my browser's dictionary either.  *Guesstimation* is about [half as popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=guesstimate%2Cguestimate%2Cguesstimation&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900) as the single-s *guestimate*.)

Answer (score 0):

You could say *hand-wavy*.

> The middle part of your answer to Question 2 is rather *hand-wavy*, but you do reach the correct result in the end.

It's rather colloquial.